# Custom Action to Update a record

Tags: global-actions

This may sound trivial but I can't find the Action type to update a record.

[image]

The help text for this dropdown says:

> A Create action lets users create records in the publisher, **Update a**
>   **Record** allows user to update data on the fields of an existing record
>   in the publisher, and a Log a Call action lets them record the details
>   of a call. A Custom action is a Visualforce page or canvas app.

But I cant find the Action for Update. What am I missing here? How do I create an action to Update a record?

Answer (score 2):

Update a Record Action Type not available in global actions. However you can add action with Update a Record type on a specific object, e.g. as an Account action.
[image]